# Tensorflow model.fit doesn't start

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

We have the following `tensorflow` model fitting code.

```py
data, labels, data_test, labels_test = get_data_and_labels()
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(data.shape[1],)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64),
        tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.keras.activations.relu, name=f"relu1"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64),
        tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.keras.activations.relu, name=f"relu2"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
        tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.keras.activations.tanh, name=f"tanh"),
    ]
)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)
model.compile(
    optimizer,
    tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
    metrics=['cosine_similarity', 'logcosh']
)

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath="model_checkpoints/cp-{epoch:04d}.ckpt", save_weights_only=True, verbose=1
)

model.fit(
    data,
    labels,
    # batch_size=64,
    epochs=200,
    callbacks=[cp_callback],
    validation_data=(data_test, labels_test),
)
```

I'm trying to fit it without `GPU` (which we currently don't have), but when I'm running the code the only thing that I get is:

```
2021-04-28 10:06:58.123786: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-04-28 10:06:58.126582: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

And it gets stuck like that **for hours** with no additional errors. We have roughly 1.4M records and we're running on Windows 10.

Is it stuck only because of the lack of `GPU`? or we should do something else?
Any help would be much valued.

Comment: Have you tested in colab?

Comment: Have you tested the code on a small subsample of your data?

Comment: @jhmt, Ye I tried with 2K samples and it ran OK

Comment: @M.Innat, I did not use any cloud platform yet. We would like to avoid that.

Comment: Test your setup with a sample dataset like mnist or cifar10 on your system and see what it gives.

Comment: @SagiShadur then it is probably related to the size of your dataset. I see you commented the `batch_size=64` does the problem persist if you set it to 64?

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem wasn't with the actual training, but with the splitting of the train-test records.

Here's how we initially did it:

```py
def split_train_test(data: pd.DataFrame, label: pd.DataFrame, test_part: float = 0.3):
    size = data.shape[0]
    test_size = int(size * test_part)

    all_indices = list(range(size))
    test_indices = list(np.random.choice(all_indices, size=test_size))
    test_indices.sort()
    train_indices = [i for i in all_indices if i not in test_indices]

    return (
        data.iloc[train_indices, :].to_numpy(),
        label.iloc[train_indices].to_numpy(),
        data.iloc[test_indices, :].to_numpy(),
        label.iloc[test_indices].to_numpy(),
    )
```

And here's how we do it now:

```py
def split_train_test(df: pd.DataFrame, test_part: float = 0.3):
    df = df.sample(frac=1)
    size = df.shape[0]
    test_size = int(size * test_part)
    data, label = df.drop(PREDICTION_FIELD, axis=1), df[PREDICTION_FIELD]

    return (
        data.iloc[:-test_size, :].to_numpy(),
        label.iloc[:-test_size].to_numpy(),
        data.iloc[-test_size:, :].to_numpy(),
        label.iloc[-test_size:].to_numpy(),
    )
```

That solved the performance issue.